# Why does UIActivityViewController call viewWillDisappear() on the presenter?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am presenting a UIActivityViewController to share an .mp4 video from a URL:

```swift
let viewController: UIViewController = ... // the presenting view controller
let url: URL = ... // local file

let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
viewController.present(activityController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

When the "save video" option is selected, the video is saved, but the presenting `UIViewController` disappears (and I can see that `.viewWillDisappear()` is called on it.)

How do I make the presenting `UIViewController` not disappear?

Note that all of the other share options that I've tried do not have this problem (messages, airdrop, instagram).

I have tried to set the `sourceView` and `sourceRect`, but it does not seem to help.

```swift
activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewController.view!
activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = viewController.view!.frame
```

I've looked for errors, but didn't find any:

```swift
activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (a: UIActivity.ActivityType?, b: Bool, c: [Any]?, d: Error?) in
    if let error = d {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Also, all of my `UIViewController` lifecycle overrides call their super, i.e.:

```swift
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: a disappearing view]

It's bringing down my entire view with it!

For what it's worth, `viewController` is setup by calling a segue that is setup in a storyboard:

```swift
class LaunchController : UIViewController {

    var performedSegue = false

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        if !performedSegue {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "main", sender: self)
            performedSegue = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried making a simple example with a single `ViewController` and I was unable to reproduce the issue, the video was saved successfully and the `ViewWillDisappear` method was not called. How are you presenting your modal view controller? Do the same error occurs with a single view controller project?

Comment: Whoah, that was fast! Good test. Added some more info to the end of the question.

Comment: Yeah I could reproduce now, this only happens when you present the `ViewController` modally. Strange issue.

Comment: Try setting modalPresentationStyle on your activityController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this "feature" was introduced by Apple in iOS 13. I tested 
this on iOS 12 and the presenting ViewController does not disappear.

I traced the call stack and it appear that UIActivityViewController is calling dismiss on presenting view controller (or it's UINavigationController) when saving to camera roll succeeds.

[image]

I don't know the way to prevent this since it's Apple private API and there's nothing in documentation about this. The only way I found, is to to set some kind of flag `savingToCameraRoll` and set it to `true` when presenting UIActivityViewController, override `dismiss` method on presenting ViewController and then check this flag inside `dismiss`.

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if !savingToCameraRoll {
         // Dismiss view controller if UIActivityViewController not in use
         super.dismiss(animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

    // Handle UIActivityViewController dismiss attempt. 
    // If you do nothing, the presenting ViewController should not be dismissed.
}
```

You should also remember to set `savingToCameraRoll` to `false` in `completionWithItemsHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard, I marked the presenting ViewController as "Is Initial View Controller" instead of presenting it via a segue. That solved the issue for me (though it's a workaround that would not work in general).